# Print All unique combos of an array in C...really close I think

Tags: c

This is a homework assignment. I am close to finishing it, but I can't get over the last hump. 
I print all possible combinations of an array, but I can't figure out how to sort out the unique combinations from all of the combinations. 
I've tried this way and a few other variations of this, but I cannot make it work, and I can't figure out why.
Size is the length of the array including the -1 value to terminate input.
Rowdata is an array of maxsize of 25. PrintFx is just a print function with a four loop to print the final array. Thanks,
Here is the code:

```
void RearrangeArray(int rowdata[],int Size)
{
int firstindex;//This is the loop control variable which controls the first permutation of the array
int secondindex;//This is the index control variable that controls the second variables     in the array
int temp[MAXROW]= {0};
int thirdindex = 0;

for (firstindex = 0; firstindex<=Size-1; firstindex++)
  {
  for (secondindex=firstindex+1; secondindex<=Size-1; secondindex++)
    {
     if(rowdata[firstindex]!=rowdata[secondindex] || thirdindex == 0)
     {
      temp[firstindex]=rowdata[firstindex];
      rowdata[firstindex]=rowdata[secondindex];
      rowdata[secondindex] = temp[firstindex];
      if(rowdata[firstindex] == rowdata[secondindex])
      {
        thirdindex=thirdindex+1;
      }
      PrintFx(rowdata, Size);
     }
    }
  }
}

Enter row data: 43101 57784 43101 57784 43101 -1
Combination #1: 57784 43101 43101 57784 43101
Combination #2: 43101 57784 43101 57784 43101
Combination #3: 57784 57784 43101 43101 43101
Combination #4: 43101 43101 57784 57784 43101
Combination #5: 43101 43101 43101 57784 57784
Combination #6: 43101 57784 57784 43101 43101
Combination #7: 43101 57784 43101 43101 57784
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pair {
    int data;
    int n;
} Kind;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return ((Kind*)a)->data - ((Kind*)b)->data ;
}

Kind *uniq(int data[], int *size){
    int i, pos;
    Kind *wk;

    wk = (Kind*)malloc(*size*sizeof(Kind));
    for(i=0;i<*size;++i){
        wk[i].data = data[i];
        wk[i].n = 1;
    }
    qsort(wk, *size, sizeof(Kind), cmp);
    pos=0;
    for(i=1;i<*size;++i){
        if(wk[pos].data != wk[i].data){
            wk[++pos].data = wk[i].data;
        } else {
            wk[pos].n += 1;
        }
    }
    *size = pos + 1;//new size
    wk = realloc(wk, *size*sizeof(Kind));

    return wk;
}

void print(Kind data[], int ksize, int store[], int size, int depth){
    int i;
    if(depth == size){
        printf("[ ");
        for(i=0;i<size;++i){
            printf("%d ", store[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<ksize;++i){
        if(data[i].n != 0){
            store[depth]=data[i].data;
            data[i].n -= 1;//update
            print(data, ksize, store, size, depth+1);
            data[i].n += 1;//restore
        }
    }
}

void printCombo(int data[], int size){
    Kind *uniq_data;
    int uniq_data_size = size;
    int *wk;

    uniq_data=uniq(data, &uniq_data_size);

    wk=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    print(uniq_data, uniq_data_size, wk, size, 0);
    free(wk);
    free(uniq_data);
}

int main(void){
    int data[] = {43101, 57784, 43101, 57784, 43101};
    int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);

    printCombo(data, size);
    return 0;
}
/*
[ 43101 43101 43101 57784 57784 ]
[ 43101 43101 57784 43101 57784 ]
[ 43101 43101 57784 57784 43101 ]
[ 43101 57784 43101 43101 57784 ]
[ 43101 57784 43101 57784 43101 ]
[ 43101 57784 57784 43101 43101 ]
[ 57784 43101 43101 43101 57784 ]
[ 57784 43101 43101 57784 43101 ]
[ 57784 43101 57784 43101 43101 ]
[ 57784 57784 43101 43101 43101 ]
*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't it also have results such as [3 1], [2 3 1], etc?

Comment: Here is an example output...I don't think the answer supplied by BLUEPIXY quite works.....actually I will put it in the main post

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well enough :/ the sample input/output is in the first post

Comment: I selected this as the answer as its closest but there should be only 7 outputs...im not quite sure whats wrong. But i will be able to resolve my problems tonight

Comment: @Liquidmetal permutations of 5 from 5 in this sample.
5P5=5!(120).
three and two in five Because of the overlap.
 It is a combination of 5!/(2!*3!) = 120 / (2 * 6) = `10`. Try to check the 10 as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This Programs Explains About the all the combinations of the Given String

For example: 
If the Given String is ICON, The Possible Combinations are

ICON 
 ICNO 
 IOCN 
 IONC 
 INCO 
 INOC 
 CION 
 CINO 
 COIN 
 CONI 
 CNIO 
 CNOI 
 OICN 
 OINC 
 OCIN 
 OCNI 
 ONIC 
 ONCI 
 NICO 
 NIOC 
 NCIO 
 NCOI 
 NOIC 
 NOCI

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
//char digits[]="0123456789";
char digits[10][5]=
{
    "ICON","CREW","FARM","OILY","CHOP","ARID","FUND","WAIT","GNAT","TEAR"
};

char str[10];
int top=0;

void push(char a) 
{
    str[top++]=a;
}

char pop() 
{
    return(str[--top]);
}

void generate(char dig[15],int n) 
{
    int i;
    char dig2[15];
    if(n==0) 
    {
        push('\0');
        printf("\n %s",str);
        pop();
    } 
    else 
    {
        for(i=0;dig[i]!='\0';i++) 
        {
            if(dig[i]!=' ') 
            {
                strcpy(dig2,dig);
                push(dig[i]);
                dig2[i]=' ';
                generate(dig2,n-1);
                pop();
            }
        }
    }
}

void main() 
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
    {
        generate(digits[i],4);
    }
}
```

http://forgetcode.com/C/1418-Program-For-All-Combination-of-the-Given-String

You can easily modify it for your requirements.

Comment: This does not exclude the case where there is overlap duplicate element.

Answer (score 0):

**Correspondence table of combination me and you.**

```
[ 43101 43101 43101 57784 57784 ]#5
[ 43101 43101 57784 43101 57784 ]
[ 43101 43101 57784 57784 43101 ]#4
[ 43101 57784 43101 43101 57784 ]#7
[ 43101 57784 43101 57784 43101 ]#2
[ 43101 57784 57784 43101 43101 ]#6
[ 57784 43101 43101 43101 57784 ]
[ 57784 43101 43101 57784 43101 ]#1
[ 57784 43101 57784 43101 43101 ]
[ 57784 57784 43101 43101 43101 ]#3

Combination #1: 57784 43101 43101 57784 43101
Combination #2: 43101 57784 43101 57784 43101
Combination #3: 57784 57784 43101 43101 43101
Combination #4: 43101 43101 57784 57784 43101
Combination #5: 43101 43101 43101 57784 57784
Combination #6: 43101 57784 57784 43101 43101
Combination #7: 43101 57784 43101 43101 57784
```